# MacOS Get trackpad pressure globally

Tags: objective-c, macos, trackpad

I'm trying to get MacBook Pro trackpad pressure with following code:

```
CGEventRef eventTapCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef eventRef, void *refcon) {
    NSEvent *event = [NSEvent eventWithCGEvent:eventRef];

    NSLog(@"%lld", (int64_t)CGEventGetIntegerValueField(eventRef, kCGMouseEventPressure)); // returns 0
    NSLog(@"%lld", (int64_t)CGEventGetIntegerValueField(eventRef, kCGTabletEventPointPressure)); // returns 0
    NSLog(@"%lld", (int64_t)CGEventGetIntegerValueField(eventRef, kCGTabletEventTangentialPressure)); // returns 0

    NSLog(@"%f", [event pressure]); // Assertion failure

    return eventRef;
}
```

Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Just a reference I found.. may or may not be useful.. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/tangentialPressure    |  + (NSEvent *)mouseEventWithType:(NSEventType)type location:(NSPoint)location modifierFlags:(NSUInteger)flags timestamp:(NSTimeInterval)time windowNumber:(NSInteger)windowNum context:(NSGraphicsContext *)context eventNumber:(NSInteger)eventNumber clickCount:(NSInteger)clickNumber pressure:(float)pressure

Comment: this is to closest sollution https://github.com/jnordberg/FingerMgmt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pressure data is available if the device supports it (i.e. a force touch trackpads). Force touch trackpads have shipped on MacBooks since circa 2015. Force touch is also available on the Magic Trackpad.

[This blog post](https://blog.eternalstorms.at/2015/11/16/how-to-detect-force-touch-capable-devices-on-the-mac/) has a method for detecting force touch devices, although I didn't try it.

My machine is a 2016 MacBook Pro with a force touch trackpad. I can get the pressure using this code:

```
[self.window trackEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskPressure 
    timeout:NSEventDurationForever 
    mode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode 
    handler:^(NSEvent * _Nonnull event, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLog(@"%f", event.pressure);
    }];
```

Output:

```
2018-02-09 18:16:10.986036-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.437820
2018-02-09 18:16:10.993772-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.457504
2018-02-09 18:16:11.001883-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.476486
2018-02-09 18:16:11.010654-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.494812
2018-02-09 18:16:11.017738-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.512497
2018-02-09 18:16:11.028129-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.529556
2018-02-09 18:16:11.033769-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.546021
2018-02-09 18:16:11.042117-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.561905
2018-02-09 18:16:11.049869-0800 forcetouch[4587:4164200] 0.577240
```

However, I see you are using an event tap.

I tried your code, and when I check `kCGMouseEventPressure` I get `1`. When I check `event.pressure` I also get `1`. So I receive a value where you do not - I guess you do not have force touch hardware? But I do not receive the actual pressure value.

I'm not sure how to get this using an event tap.

This works for me on a 2016 MacBook Pro. Note that this machine has a force touch trackpad. I'm not sure what this will return on a machine without the force touch trackpad. However hopefully this gives you some more ideas.

[Force touch for developers](https://developer.apple.com/macos/force-touch/)

[NSEvent - pressure](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534543-pressure?language=objc)

Comment: AppKit appears to look into an unexposed field (`CGEventField` 148) to access Force Touch pressure data. I think the best way to gain access to this in an event tap through public API is probably to create an `NSEvent` around the `CGEvent` and then request its pressure.

Answer (score 3):

The snippet from the answer above:

```c
[self.window trackEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskPressure 
    timeout:NSEventDurationForever 
    mode:NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode 
    handler:^(NSEvent * _Nonnull event, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        NSLog(@"%f", event.pressure);
    }];
```

appears to be **stopping the window from responding to any mouse events**. I think it may be due to this quote from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419727-trackevents

> Each event is removed from the event queue and then passed to the tracking handler

I am not an expert in Cocoa's event architecture, but it occurs to me that `trackEventsMachingTask` intercepts the event.

My workaround is this:

```c
NSEvent *(^monitor)(NSEvent *event) = ^NSEvent *(NSEvent *event) {
    NSLog(@"pressure = %f", event.pressure);
    return event;
};

[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskPressure
                                      handler:monitor];
```

According to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534971-addlocalmonitorforevents,
`addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask`'s block argument is passed the pointer to the event, and as long as the block does not return `nil`, the event is dispatched regularly.